# Check if a date falls on a bank holiday, weekend or after 6 PM and if yes, push it to the next working day

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with list of dates and a bank holiday flag for each in BigQuery. For each date I make the following checks:

- Is it bank holiday?
- Is it a weekend?
- Is it after 6 PM UTC?

If any of these is yes, we move the date to the next working day (9AM UTC).

Doing it separately is easy, but I'm having problem since when I adjust the date I also have to find the next available date. E.g. if a date falls on weekend, I move it to Monday, but then have to check if that Monday is actually a holiday. If yes, move it to Tuesday. Then, again, check if Tue is also a holiday.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a table with bank holidays? Or how should it be identified?

Comment: Yes, I have a separate table with bank holidays already identified.

Comment: You probably need to write this as a function where you can have a loop that checks if the date/time requires you to adjust the date. If the check fails you exit the loop and return the date; if the check passes then you add a day to the date and go round the loop again

Answer (score 0):

You may generate enough dates forward from the current date using `generate_date_array`, join them to the holiday calendar and then decide if you need to get current transaction date or the next working date.

Below is an example code with comments:

```
, get_dates as (
  select
    t.*
    , array(
        select calendar
        /*Generate 30 days after the current date to cover enough time interval*/
        from unnest(
            generate_date_array(cast(t.trx_date as date), cast(t.trx_date + interval 30 day as date))
          ) as calendar
            /*Identify holidays in these 30 future days*/
            left join holidays
            on calendar = holidays.dt
        /*Place non-holidays first, then sort by dates.
          It will arrange current date at the first place if it is not a holiday
          or the next working day at the first place if current date is holiday*/
        order by holidays.dt nulls first, calendar asc
        /*To capture two consecutive working days to process times after 6 PM*/
        limit 2
    ) as dates
  from transactions as t
)
select
  t.trx_date
  , case
      when
        /*after 6 PM*/
        extract(hour from t.trx_date) >= 18
        /* ... on working day - the first element of dates*/
        and cast(t.trx_date as date) = dates[0]
      then cast(dates[1] + interval 9 hour as timestamp)
      /*If current date is not a working day*/
      when cast(t.trx_date as date) != dates[0]
      /*... then get the next working day*/
      then cast(dates[0] + interval 9 hour as timestamp)
      else t.trx_date
    end as actual_trx_date
from get_dates as t
```

which for this sample data (based on our holiday calendar)

```
with holidays as (
  select *
  from unnest([
    date '2023-03-08',
    date '2023-05-08',
    date '2023-05-09'
  ]) as dt
)
, transactions as (
  select *
  from unnest([
    timestamp '2023-03-07 12:00:30',
    timestamp '2023-03-07 18:15:00',
    timestamp '2023-03-08 10:00:00',
    timestamp '2023-03-08 18:00:00',
    timestamp '2023-03-09 10:00:00',
    timestamp '2023-03-11 10:00:00',
    timestamp '2023-05-05 10:00:00',
    timestamp '2023-05-05 19:00:00'
  ]) as trx_date
)
```

returns

| trx_date | actual_trx_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-03-07 12:00:30.000000 UTC | 2023-03-07 12:00:30.000000 UTC |
| 2023-03-07 18:15:00.000000 UTC | 2023-03-09 09:00:00.000000 UTC |
| 2023-03-08 10:00:00.000000 UTC | 2023-03-09 09:00:00.000000 UTC |
| 2023-03-08 18:00:00.000000 UTC | 2023-03-09 09:00:00.000000 UTC |
| 2023-03-09 10:00:00.000000 UTC | 2023-03-09 10:00:00.000000 UTC |
| 2023-03-11 10:00:00.000000 UTC | 2023-03-11 10:00:00.000000 UTC |
| 2023-05-05 10:00:00.000000 UTC | 2023-05-05 10:00:00.000000 UTC |
| 2023-05-05 19:00:00.000000 UTC | 2023-05-06 09:00:00.000000 UTC |